# C++ .net "Unable to load assembly XX.XX"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, designer

I'm developing C++.net 2.0 under Win7 with VS2008.  I am working with several layers of UserControls.

I have a DLL Names "MyControls.dll" that contains a control, derived from a control in "BaseControls.dll".

Every time I attempt to load any controls in MyControls that derive from BaseControls, the designer breaks with the error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'BCVSTools, Version=1.0.3831.15051, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

The dll's are all in the same project, compiled in succession, on the same drive, not on the network, very straightforward.  I tried adding my references using both **project** and **dll reference**.  BaseControls.dll does compile unmanaged code, but I know this is possible, it works on my coworkers machine several desks down.

I cannot get the damn designer to load for the life of me!

Any ideas?

Edit: Things Ive tried)

- Changing reference from project to dll and vice-versa
- Rebuilding project, restarting app\pc\vs
- Removing and readding references
- resetting toolbox
- changing intranet permissions to full

Here's some outputs from the assembly bind logger.  This is one of MY two dll's that failed to load.  In addition to those two, one other dll: MSVCM90D failed to load as well.  Let me know if I should post them as well.

---

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (6/28/2010 @ 10:29:45 AM) ***
```

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = BAUERCONTROLS\robertson
LOG: DisplayName = BCVSTools, Version=1.0.3831.15051, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL

## Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: This is an inspection only bind.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/BCVSTools.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/BCVSTools/BCVSTools.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/BCVSTools.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/BCVSTools/BCVSTools.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/BCVSTools.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/BCVSTools/BCVSTools.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/BCVSTools.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/BCVSTools/BCVSTools.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/BCVSTools.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/BCVSTools/BCVSTools.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/BCVSTools.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/BCVSTools/BCVSTools.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

Comment: Run fuslogvw.exe and document what it shows you.